# Сортировка элементов в таблице

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Здравствуйте!

Допустим, у нас есть таблица:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Колонка 1</th>
<th>Колонка 2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Название 1</td><td>Статус 1: -<br>Покупка 2: +<br>Продажа 3: -</td></tr>
<tr><td>Название 2</td><td>Статус 1: +<br>Покупка 2: -<br>Продажа 3: +</td></tr>
<tr><td>Название 3</td><td>Статус 1: -<br>Покупка 2: -<br>Продажа 3: +</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Нужно произвести сортировку по колонке 2 таким образом, чтобы можно было выбрать:

- Сортировать по "Статус 1"
- Сортировать по "Продажа 2"
- Сортировать по "Продажа 3"

При этом стоит учитывать, что количество статусов может быть абсолютно разным. Но в каждом ряде названия отличаться не будут (т.е. если в первом ряде "Статус 1", "Продажа 2", "Продажа 3" - то и в других рядах будут те же названия, т.е. не будет такого, что в первом ряде "Статус 1", а во втором "Статус 150").

Я думаю, что стоит действовать так:

- Определить все элементы в первом ряде второго столбца (если брать из примера: Статус 1, Покупка 2, Продажа 3).
- Если пользователь хочет сделать сортировку по "Покупка 2", то всё, что идет до "Покупка 2", удаляется; всё, что идет после "Покупка 2: [+-]`<br>`" - тоже удаляется, далее удаляется "Покупка 2:" и производится сортировка.

Честно говоря, очень трудно представляю как такое можно реализовать и поэтому обращаюсь к более сообразительным и опытным разработчикам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отделите данные от представления:

```
var data = [{
        'Название' : 1,
        'Статус 1' : '-',
        'Покупка 2': '+',
        'Продажа 3': '-'
    },{
        'Название' : 2,
        'Статус 1' : '+',
        'Покупка 2': '-',
        'Продажа 3': '+'
    },...];
```

потом отобразите эти данные в ДОМ, через темплейты, или напрямую, как вам угодно, если не знаете - это уже другой вопрос

далее, когда вам надо будет сортировать данные, просто делаете:

```
data.sort(function(a,b){ /* ваша логика */ });
```

и перерендериваете в ДОМ

- [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)